# Assistance with Access Forms, Tables, and Relationships

Tags: database, ms-access

### Summary

I've been asked to create an Access Database for a local business as a personal favour. I've dabbled in Access before - hence why I was asked - but I'm having some difficulties. Mainly because I haven't worked with databases in years!

I've created my Tables and my Forms and have successfully linked them all together, but I'm having some trouble with a specific issue.

**I have two Forms as shown below:**

[image: New Case Form]

[image: New Client Form]

### Details

The "New Case" Form will allow the user to open a new Case by saving information to the "Cases" Table. Each Case will then need Two Clients; respectively known as "Client One" and "Client Two"; which will be inputted using the "New Client" Form, accessed by clicking the "Modify Details" Button. These details will then be stored in the "Clients" Table.

I have a casual understanding of Relationships, and I understand that I somehow need to create a working Relationship between Cases and Clients, but what I'm looking to do is the following:

When the user adds Client details using the "New Client" Form, I then want the details to be displayed on the "New Case" Form inside each Box (E.G. Client's Name will go where marked.)

**What is the best way to achieved this?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have read several articles and scrolled through many forums, and whilst they proved helpful, I'm still unable to wrap my head around a solution.

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 0):

Well, your workflow should be a “bit” different.

You have a nice form to add a case. And you should have a form to add Clients (but not necessary a form that adds a new client to a case). The reasoning here is once you add a client, then it can be used over and over for many cases in the future – you don’t want to have to re-enter that data.

So your form case should have the ability to “select” a client, but if that client does not exist, then you can add that client and then select that client to the case.

And while you limited the case to two clients, what happens in the future if you want 3 clients? I would not limit your design to only two clients for future business changes. However, let’s just stick with two clients.

The easy way to do this is to add two columns to your case:

lngClient1
lngClinet2

The above will be the two columns in cases that “points” or “relates” back to clients. However, you don’t really need to setup any enforced relationships here, but just use the ability of the system to connect such tables together as required.

Once you have above, then add two combo boxes to your case form to select the client. (Use the wizard to create the combo boxes, make sure the first column is the auto number id of client, and then display name and perhaps company as additional columns in the combo box.

With above, you have to add the client(s) first, and then launch the case form, and enter information, and then use the two combo boxes to select the two clients. The two combo boxes will be bound to lngClinet1 and lngClient2 columns in the case form.